Determining the performance Impact of firewalld rule count
I was working on tweaking the performance of fail2ban and I read that a too-long ban can result in a build-up of rules that will negatively impact performance, which made me wonder, "Is there any particular idea of a number of rules that is 'too high' for nftables?"
I currently use firewalld with nftables as the backend, and maybe 10-20 rules.
However, a few servers are specifically intended for audiences of certain countries and should not be accessed outside them. If I pull down a country-IP database (e.g. MaxMind) and then generate a list of rules for all CIDRs for countries outside the allowed list, I end up with nearly 17,000 rules.
On one hand, that's a lot of rules (IMHO), but on the other hand, there's nothing but spam and hack attempts coming from outside the designated countries (even legitimate users traveling abroad need to VPN into the US before they can access anyway).
Is that kind of volume going to negatively impact nftables? I assume that the impact is relative to the amount of volume that has to be checked, but I haven't found a good way to see or measure the impact of the rules, and I don't want to start loading up thousands of rules without knowing the possible ramifications ahead of time.

I would start by looking into performance impact of many rules
Rule Matching Algorithm: Nftables uses a more efficient rule matching algorithm compared to its predecessor iptables. However, with a very high number of rules (like 17,000), the performance can still be affected because each packet needs to be checked against the rules until a match is found or the end of the list is reached.
The processing power and memory of your server play a significant role. More powerful hardware can handle a larger number of rules more efficiently.
How the rules are structured and organized can also influence performance. For instance, grouping similar rules together and minimizing the number of chains can help improve performance.
Once we've got that clear, then focus on the most relevant items:
IP Sets: Instead of creating individual rules for each IP range, you can use ipsets to group IP addresses or ranges together. This reduces the number of rules and can significantly improve performance. Nftables supports sets, which are more efficient for handling large numbers of IP addresses.
nft add set ip filter allowed_countries { type ipv4_addr\; }
nft add rule ip filter input ip saddr @allowed_countries accept

Use tools like nft monitor to see how the rules are being applied and if there are any performance bottlenecks. Monitoring CPU and memory usage while testing different rule configurations can help identify the optimal setup.
Apply rules in batches during off-peak hours to reduce the immediate load on the server.
Here are some documents where you can find more comprehensive information:
The official nftables wiki provides comprehensive information about how nftables works and how to optimize it.
Nftables Wiki
Some studies and articles discuss the performance impact of nftables compared to iptables and best practices for using nftables.
Nftables performance analysis
The firewalld documentation includes best practices and performance tips for managing a large number of firewall rules
Firewalld documentation
By leveraging sets and monitoring performance, you can manage a large number of firewall rules more efficiently with nftables and mitigate potential performance issues.
Good luck!
